# Difference between "SQL server 2008 standard" and "SQL server 2008 standard for small business"?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

There seems to be a big difference in price for these licenses, but after a lot of googling I can't find any info on how the two compare.

The blurb for the "small business" version is:

"This edition of SQL Server is an entry level edition that is intended for use in small single-server office environments with a small user base. SQL Server Standard for Small Business provides the capabilities of SQL Server Standard Edition."

So if it provides the same capability as SQL Server Standard Edition, and it runs on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard - what exactly am I losing by buying the "small business" package?

---

Ok - after the hint from Squillman, I looked for SBS info, rather than SQL server info and found this:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/628692/sql-server-2008-standard-small-business-does-not-install-on-windows-2008-standard

Basically, it says on the box that the software will install on Windows Server 2008 standard - but it will only do that if the server is in an SBS domain - and that requirement isn't mentioned anywhere.

Doesn't look like MS ever got back to the person who complained back in Dec.

At least it's not just me that found it confusing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a licensing question. Like a "student" edition or other fancy licensing tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**Windows Small Business Server Editions Overview**](http://www.microsoft.com/sbs/en/us/editions-overview.aspx) (near the bottom of the page):

> - SQL Server 2008 R2 for Small Business featuring a range of features
>     that can help businesses maximize the value of their information with
>     greater capabilities in development, manageability, business
>     intelligence, and data warehousing. SQL Server 2008 R2 for Small
>     Business has exactly the same capabilities as SQL Server 2008 R2
>     Standard, however it is only available to use in the SBS 2011
>     environment.

The key being the last line, only available for SBS.  If you want just SQL with nothing else then you'll have to buy a normal SQL Server Standard license.

(It would be nice if Microsoft would also mention it on the SQL Server Editions Overview as well.)

Comment: That's exactly what I thought - but according to the quoted OS requirements (from several vendors), it's apparently compatible with Windows Server 2008 Standard, not just the SBS edition. Which is what's confusing me.

Comment: Compatible from a technical standpoint, yes.  Licensing, not so much.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I've found some more info now (added to my original question).